# jQuery : Load images with specific order and callback on end queue

Tags: jquery, image, load

I try to find a way to have a queue pattern to load some images (or other stuff) and launch something when all finish, the idea his to have for example a function like this :

```
/**
* the idea
* @param [] urls Each url to load
* @param function onDone When queue is finish and OK
* @param function onFail When queue is finish and KO append
* @param function onLoad When a specific url finish to load
* @param function onError When specific url fail to load
* @return promise (https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)
*/
jQuery.loadImages = function(urls, onDone, onFail, onLoad, onError){
    onFail = onFail || function(){};
    onLoad = onLoad || function(){};
    onError = onError || function(){};

    var queue = new Queue();
    urls.map(function(url){
        queue.add( jQuery.loadImage(url, onLoad, onError) ); // here the systme to add in the queue in which I add my promise return by jQuery.loadImage
    });
    queue.finish(onDone, onFail);

    return queue; // this must be a promise
};
```

I have yet the code for load one image as a promise :

```
jQuery.loadImage = function(url, onLoad, onError) {
    function load(deferred){
        function _onLoad(){
            off();
            onLoad && onLoad(image);
            deferred.resolve(image);
        }

        function _onError(){
            off();
            onError && onError(image);
            deferred.reject(image);
        }

        function off() {
            image.onload = image.onerror = image.onabort = null; // le onabort est pour IE
        }

        var image = new Image();

        image.onload = _onLoad;
        image.onerror = _onError;
        image.onabort = _onError;
        image.src = url;
    };

    return jQuery.Deferred(load).promise();
};
```

I find this : http://jsfiddle.net/coffeeandcode/yg9P6/ but it appear to use "setTimeout" which is I think a bad practice, furthermore it's not possible to add onDone/onFail.

**Edit 1** : I try something which is suppose to work : https://jsfiddle.net/jyuj1w9q/3/ (look console log to saw results) but with this example, you can see, second image (apple) which is with an heavy size in logged on third place, furthermore onDone not run -_-

Comment: Maybe you looking for [`jQuery.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)? You can pass to this function multiple promises. Once they all call `resolve`, the callback function will call.

Comment: The problem with "when" is all promise added in arguments are executed as same time and not in specific order, so it's not a queue pattern but asynchronous pattern.
Say in other way, if I have this for example : ["cat.jpg", "apple.jpg", "dog.jpg"], "cat" must load first and after "apple" load and only after that two load "dog" is load.